# Scikit: Changing the value of C

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I've been looking at the documentation for scikit for so long, and it says I am able to change the value of C in the SVC to a different value, but I can't see to find the actual code to do so. I want to see the results of changing it to different values. I took the code from the documentation like so:

```
>>> X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> Y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, Y) 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
gamma=0.0, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

But instead of the values for X, Y they have, I have my own arrays. My question is, how can I change the value of C in the SVC to a number other than 1.0.

Comment: Basically any example involving SVC and the docstring are pretty explicit: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC

Answer (score 1):

You specify it as an optional argument to the constructor, i.e.,

```
>>> clf = svm.SVC(C=2)
>>> clf.fit(X, Y) 
SVC(C=2, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>>
```

Comment: Or even by doing ``clf.C = 2`` (before calling fit)